how to add images to the strips of slides in latex?
I would like to add two images to the both strips of slides: one for each. The example is as follows:
\documentclass{beamer}

% Packages for positioning images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

% Define colors
\definecolor{primarycolor}{RGB}{0,102,204} % Example color
\definecolor{secondarycolor}{RGB}{255,255,255} % Example color

%% Set fonts
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arial}

% Use standard LaTeX font packages if not using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Add background images
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,-30){\includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth]{seal.png}} % Bottom strip image
        \put(0,-270){\includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth]{ksu.png}} % Top strip image
    \end{picture}
}

The problem is that both the top and bottom strips of slides do not show up: only the pictures.

What I really want is like the following:


You do not provide a compilable document,  so it is  impossible know what are you doing really, but what strips  you expect if seems that you are not using any theme? If you add  some like \usetheme{Madrid} to the preamble you will see top and bottom strips, but obviously covering in part your images, because you put that images in the background of the slide.  If you don't know how to explain well the issue, it would be helpful add a compilable MWE,  take the screenshot of the slide, and modify it at hand with a drawing program to show how it should look.

Thanks for your help. That's a very good point. Please check the updated version for what I want.

Use \setbeamertemplate to customize parts of the presentation. Besides the manual, search and print the "Beamer appearance cheat sheet" in google to have a reference of the names of that parts if you love mess with that hairy beast.
The format of the strips can be done in several ways, with or without tikz, with or without tables, etc. The main point is that the method that you use place the elements that where you want to include in the right place and not elsewhere.  One way is place the elements that you want in this strips inside a beamercolorbox including the images, taking care that the structure color match with the background of the images. The following MWE is only a first attempt. Feel free to modify at your convenience.

\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{ksu}{HTML}{512888} % Example color
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=ksu!30,fg=ksu}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=ksu}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\small}%
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=white,bg=ksu}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=ksu!50!black, bg=ksu!10}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[ball]

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\nointerlineskip
\vspace*{-1.35ex}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.3cm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
\vspace*{-1.35ex}
\parbox[b]{.7\linewidth}{%
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\\[1ex]
\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\\[-6pt]}
\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo1.png}}
\end{beamercolorbox}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\begin{beamercolorbox}{footline}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2.png}
\end{beamercolorbox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My KSU frame title}{My KSU frame subtitle}
The \structure{KSU} template
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item foo 
\item Item bar
\end{enumerate}
\begin{block}{foo}
Foo bar baz 
\begin{itemize}
\item Item foo 
\item Item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}

Edit
If you do not want subtitles, but a single line title, you can set the frametitle to some like:
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.3cm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle
\raisebox{-.5em}[0pt]{\makebox[8cm][c]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo1.png}}}
\vspace*{-1.25ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}


Or:
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.3cm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
\begin{tabular}{cp{.4\linewidth}}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle  & 
\vspace*{-3.5ex}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{logo1.png} 
\vspace{-4ex} \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-.7ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}

Or to overlap te the logo with the title:
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.3cm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
\rlap{\hspace{.2\linewidth}\raisebox{-1.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo1.png}}}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle
\end{beamercolorbox}}



First, thanks for your help-it works. I think the top stripe is too high-I tried to remove the subtitle of the frame to make it short, but then the frame title is not centered vertically. Please read my answer for details.

Now, it is perfect. Thank you so much. My last question: I wonder how you got the  color as \definecolor{ksu}{HTML}{512888} % Example color? You just take a look at the two images I attached and then figure it out. You know, I got mine from ChatGPT as follows:  % Define colors \definecolor{primarycolor}{RGB}{0,102,204} % Example color \definecolor{secondarycolor}{RGB}{255,255,255} % Example color but yours is much better.

Several tools allow you to pick the color of some image and obtain the exact  RGB value and/or  the hexadecimal HTML code  (e.g.; Gimp and Inkscape)., but in this concrete case you only need to search in Google "KSU purple" to realize that the exact RGB value  is 81,40,136  (or  512888 in HTML). In case of color of official logos is always better find out the corporate specifications because  logo images obtained from some web page may have been manipulated and saved with significant color changes.

thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.
